# class is not key value coding-compliant for the key navigationBar

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationbar

I have added a UINavigationbar and UIscrollView to UIView(SecondView).When I click a button in firstView it should take me to secondView.
On button click :

```
 SecondView *secondview=[[SecondView alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
 [self presentModalViewController: secondview animated:NO]; //error at this line 
 [secondview release];
```

In the secondView.h

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navigationBar;
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIScrollView *testscroll;
```

SecondView.m:

```
@synthesize navigationBar,testscroll;
```

But Im getting error like :

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: SecondView  setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key navigationBar.

My secondView.xib is like this :

Couldnot understand where Im going wrong?

Comment: [self presentModalViewController: secondview animated:yes];.. may be it will work and if you want to push that class you have to write... [self.navigationController pushViewController:secView animated:YES];

Comment: @Sudha he is not asking for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself.
I was wrong with nothing.Everything was OK.
I have added a new view and made the same connections and got it.Don't know why this happens regularly in xcode.

Comment: it was due to outlet connections as i told you .... you recreated all the things, then it solved the probs

Comment: This can be caused by inconsistencies in the resources of the installed application. Try removing the app and reinstalling it. Cleaning your project may also help.

Answer (score 9):

This error generally comes when you have created an outlet in your xib and then by mistake (or knowingly) you have deleted that iboutlet object, or vice versa.

So check your xib's iboutlet connections carefully.

Comment: I have checked them and just pasted the screen shot .Can u please have a look and let me know

Answer (score 2):

Check the spelling:

> @property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navigationBar;
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
> reason: SecondView setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key
> value coding-compliant for the key navigationbar.

Note the difference of `navigationBar` and `navigationbar`, it's case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

you can presenting ModelViweController With navigationbar like this way:-

```
SecondView *objSecondView = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navbar = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:objSecondView];

// add navigation bar image at hear

     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_launcher.png"];
                [navbar.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
     navbar.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

     [self presentModalViewController:navbar animated:YES];
```

and you can Push One View to Another View like:-

```
SecondView *objSecondView =[[SecondView alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objSecondView animated:YES];
```

**NOTE**

Some time its error occurs because of we are putting wrong Nib name at this line of code : `initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];`

**UPDATE**

no need to add navbar tin image at SecondViewcontroller you can add all stuff hear like barbuttonItem, tincolor , navigatin BackgroudnColor ect.

Comment: but mine is not a navigationbased application and also im adding navigationbar programatically in SecondView like - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"c_launcher.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
    imageView.frame =CGRectMake(0,0,120,45);
    [self.navigationBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,70)];
   self.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.navigationBar addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];
}.then can I go with ur code?

Answer (score 0):

`pushViewController:` is used to push a UIViewController. It looks like `SecondView` is a UIView, not a UIViewController.

Comment: It is a UIViewController only not a UIView.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not connect some object to the File's Owner in that UIViewController's xib.

Check one time my friend.

Answer (score 0):

If you face this problem again,
try to: select File's Owner then click on the "Connection Inspector" (upper on the top of right pane), you will see all the outlets. Look for any sign like this (!) you will find it on the small circle which indicates a **missing outlet**, all you have to do is linking it properly or remove the outlet.

Answer (score 0):

1. For erroneous case Rakesh provided correct answer (outlet was deleted - need accurately check your xib's / storyboards) with small addition:
   it might be also caused by renaming outlet by simply "Find&Replace". In such case the outlet is re-named everywhere in sources, but not in storyboard.
   In such case make sure you accurately renamed the outlet in storyboards too, e.g.:

   grep -r --include "*.storyboard" navigationBar .
2. Than everything looks to be ok: XCode caching your xib's, to fix the behavior:

   - clean build
   - remove app from device/simulator
   - restart the app
     Restart simulator might be also necessary (for me never was required for device)